# Split Delimiter java

Tags: java, split, delimiter

> i've found an answer when searching in stackoverflow, it works
> perfectly but when i saw the comment the user doesn't explain how the
> code works, can someone explain to me how does this code means?....

```
String input =
      "        [John, 8, 9, 10, \r\n"
    + "       , Peter, 10, 8, 7, \r\n"
    + "       , Steve, 8, 9, 6, \r\n"
    + "         ]";
String output = input.replaceAll("(?m)^[\\s,\\[]+|[\\s,\\]]+$|[\\s&&[^\r\n]]+", "");
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Is there a question here?  You should at least re-state the original question so that we have some context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67994102/add-newline-for-string-java
the questions have been closed recently.

Comment: @JansenStanlie what part don't you understand? You need to ask a particular question.

Comment: [\\s&&[^\r\n]]+" this the part i dont understand at all, i don't get where the comma disappear while the is nocomma delimiter, and only bracket delimter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question from the comment:

*"[\s&&[^\r\n]]+" this the part i dont understand at all, i don't get where the comma disappear while the is nocomma delimiter, and only bracket delimter" – Jansen Stanlie*

I will ignore the string escapes and write it as true regex.
In the java flavor of regex you can do class intersections and subtractions by using:

**[..&&[..]]** and **[..&&[^..]** respectively. Replace .. with your character class and inclusion/exclusion range.

For instance

**[a-z&&[^aeiou]]** would give you an english lowercase letter that is not a vowel.

So, in your example (removing java string escape)
**[\s&&[^\r\n]]** - \s any whitespace character, except \r or \n. This was done to get rid of all spaces but keep the line breaks.

This could also be written as
**[\s&&[\V]]** which would make it Unicode compliant. \V is any character that is **NOT** a vertical whitespace.

The question about where the comma is removed:
The leading comma is removed here:

```
(?m)^[\\s,\\[]+|[\\s,\\]]+$|[\\s&&[^\r\n]]+
         ^
```

and trailing:

```
(?m)^[\\s,\\[]+|[\\s,\\]]+$|[\\s&&[^\r\n]]+
                    ^
```

Comment: What does (?m)^ stands for

Comment: the (?m) is just an inline way to tell the parser that it should be multiline. The ^ matches the beginning of the input, in this case the beginning of each line.

Comment: Thnkyou so much, u help me understand a lot